# Insert multiple rows from a single row inside an insert into select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, insert, bulkinsert

I have (a more complex version of) the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Messages (
    ItemId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    DeliveryType INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE NotificationsQueue (
    ItemId INT NOT NULL,
    DeliveryType INT NOT NULL
);
```

The possible values for DeliveryType are:

```
0 -> none
1 -> mail
2 -> email
3 -> both
```

Now, having some entries in the Messages table:

```
INSERT INTO Messages(Name, DeliveryType) Values
('Test0', 0),
('Test1', 1),
('Test2', 2),
('Test3', 3)
```

I need to populate the NotificationsQueue table like so:

- when DeliveryType = 0, don't insert anything
- when DeliveryType = 1 OR DeliveryType = 2, insert a tuple: (ItemId, DeliveryType)
- when DeliveryType = 3, insert two tuples: (ItemId, 1), (ItemId, 2)

My attempt to do so resulted in these two queries:

```
INSERT INTO NotificationsQueue (ItemId, DeliveryType) SELECT ItemId, 1 AS DeliveryType FROM Messages WHERE DeliveryType IN (1, 3)
INSERT INTO NotificationsQueue (ItemId, DeliveryType) SELECT ItemId, 2 AS DeliveryType FROM Messages WHERE DeliveryType IN (2, 3)
```

Even though this works, the select statements for the inserts are much more complex in practice, so I was wondering if there's any good way to merge them in a single query, in order to avoid duplication.

PS: I am not allowed to change the schema or add duplicate items in the `Messages` table.

Comment: Sure, but I still need to select stuff from other tables, because `Messages` does not contain all the information I need to put in `NotificationsQueue`. How would I get away with a single `INSERT` statement, even inside the trigger?

Comment: Well, could you gather the information in variables and after that insert the values?

Comment: Mmmm, OK, come to think of it, that might not be so bad, if I use a trigger with an IF statement. Thanks for the hint! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use trigger you can do this

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.Messages_Inserted ON dbo.[Messages]
    FOR INSERT
AS
    INSERT INTO dbo.[NotificationsQueue]
            ( ItemId
            ,DeliveryType
            )
            SELECT ItemId
                   ,1
                FROM INSERTED
                WHERE DeliveryType IN ( 1, 3 )
            UNION ALL
            SELECT ItemId
                   ,2
                FROM INSERTED
                WHERE DeliveryType IN ( 2, 3 )
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.[Messages](Name, DeliveryType) Values
('Test0', 0),
('Test1', 1),
('Test2', 2),
('Test3', 3)

SELECT * FROM dbo.[Messages]
SELECT * FROM dbo.NotificationsQueue
```

Comment: Yep, that sounds doable. [@PeterRing](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3056555/peterring)'s comment gave me a similar idea which I'll try out now.

Comment: This will also accommodate times when you insert more than 1 more into a table at once. When using variables you need to consider that more than 1 row will be inserted but variable only hold last value assigned to it.

Comment: OK, fair enough :) Thanks again!

Comment: I am accepting this answer for the trigger idea, but I ended up combining it with [@EricZ](http://stackoverflow.com/users/745430/ericz)'s creative CTE query from the [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22666423/1174378).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want everything in one select, I would create a look up table to translate the type, like this

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1,1),(2,2),(3,1),(3,2)) a(DeliveryType,type)) 
SELECT ItemId, t.type AS DeliveryType 
FROM Messages m
INNER JOIN    cte t
    ON t.DeliveryType = m.DeliveryType
```

Comment: Where there's a will, there's always a way! Thanks for the creative solution, but I think the trigger will be cleaner in my case.

Comment: Actually, this is very useful, even when I'm using the trigger. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
INSERT INTO NotificationsQueue (ItemId, DeliveryType) 
select itemid, case when deliverytype = 3 then n else deliverytype end
from messages
inner join (values(1), (2)) x(n) on n <= case when deliverytype=1 then 2 else deliverytype end -1
```

Comment: The CTE look up table that @EricZ came up with seems nicer, but thank you.